# Microsoft C++ exception: fl::i18n::MwLcDataNotFound?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

When running my application, immediately when I start my application (before my first line of code gets executed), I get about ~100 lines of

```
First-chance exception at 0x759bb9bc in myApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: fl::i18n::MwLcDataNotFound at memory location 0x00cce9e4..
First-chance exception at 0x759bb9bc in myApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: fl::i18n::MwLcDataNotFound at memory location 0x00cce9e4..
First-chance exception at 0x759bb9bc in myApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: fl::i18n::MwLcDataNotFound at memory location 0x00ccea6c..
```

in the Visual Studio output window. I have never seen this before and I have absolutely no clue where it comes from. Google doesn't spit out a single result. Does anyone know where this could come from or how I could find out?

I'm using CMake with VS2010, my app uses opencv, boost_program_options and matlab libmat/libmx.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of MATLAB. It means that the MATLAB library could not find ICU data files. This is a non-serious problem.

Comment: Really, are you sure? Could you maybe be more specific (or provide a link)?
How could I go and fix this? I really really don't like this kind of stuff and want to fix it, even if its non-serious.

If you read my comments below, I dont get the exceptions on another system, which should have an identical matlab installation.

Comment: It seems like you're right. Call stack shows ntdll -> libmwi18n.dll (matlab) -> libexpat.dll -> KernelBase.dll. But I still can't find anything about it on google. Could you provide me with some more details please?

Comment: @Ela782: Try googling just the exception name, and just the containing namespace. Both come back indicating that the name belongs to a MATLAB runtime library, and that missing ICU files are the cause.

Comment: Hm, I think you must have another google. I tried both (and more) before I even posted here, and now again, yielding barely any result, and not one useful one?