# Linking libmat in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to include the libmat library to be able to read .mat files in C++, however I've not been able to link it properly eventhough I've set it up exactly the same way as I have other libraries. I've tried two different approaches, but both fail.

First of all, I've added the following links in the project preferences:

VC++ Directories > Library Directories: C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\extern\lib\win32\microsoft

VC++ Directories > Include Directories: C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\extern\include

C/C++ > Additional Include Directories: C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\extern\include

Linker > Input > Additional Dependecies: libmat.lib; libmx.lib; libmex.lib

And added the libmat.dll, libmex.dll and libmx.dll to the debug folder of the project.

---

Method 1:

```
#include "mat.h"
MATFile* file = matOpen("examplefile.mat","r");
```

I then get the following error:

```
First-chance exception: Microsoft C++ exception: fl::i18n::MwLcDataNotFound
```

---

Method 2:

```
#include "mat.h"

std::string  DLLFilename = "libmat.dll";
HMODULE libHandle = LoadLibrary(DLLFilename.c_str());

// I can comment out the following lines and the error persists
MATFile *(*myMatOpen)(const char*, const char*);
myMatOpen = (MATFile*(*)(const char*, const char*))GetProcAddress(libHandle, "matOpen");
```

And I get the same error using this method.

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot directly comment on the error you're getting... But  you'll not be able to read/write any data from/to a matfile, without linking to `libmx` (and `libmex` maybe) as well. Maybe that will solve this solves the problem above too...

Comment: No, that's not it, I'm afraid. Edited the OP so that it's clear that I've added them as well. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269887/2319400 That's what google spat out on "MwLcDataNotFound"

Comment: @Sebastian You beat me by a few seconds, I'd found the same - it seems like this is a runtime issue rather than a linker problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that thread but I didn't understand what I could do to avoid it.

Comment: @FabianJonsson it seems like your program compiles and links ok but gives you a first-chance exception when you run it - is this correct? If so, and [if this answer is the cause](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94667) it seems to be non-fatal. How are you determining if your `matOpen` succeeds?

Comment: I haven't looked at the output from the function yet, as the build process dies when it reaches the matOpen line. If it's non-fatal, how do I get it to proceed?